# Get unique values along axis in a Numpy 4d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, multidimensional-array

Given an array (representing an image with 3 rows of 19 RGB pixels) like the following:

```
test_nested_array = np.array([[[
       [  6.,  11.,  14.],
       [  6.,  11.,  14.],
       [  6.,  11.,  14.],
       [  6.,  11.,  14.],
       [  7.,  12.,  15.],
       [  7.,  12.,  15.],
       [  7.,  12.,  15.],
       [  7.,  12.,  15.],
       [  7.,  15.,  18.],
       [  7.,  15.,  18.],
       [  8.,  13.,  16.],
       [  8.,  13.,  16.],
       [  8.,  13.,  17.],
       [  8.,  16.,  19.],
       [  8.,  16.,  19.],
       [  8.,  16.,  19.],
       [ 10.,  15.,  18.],
       [ 10.,  18.,  21.],
       [ 15.,  24.,  29.]],

       [[  15.,  11.,  14.],
       [  13.,  11.,  14.],
       [  15.,  11.,  14.],
       [  11.,  11.,  14.],
       [  7.,  19.,  15.],
       [  7.,  12.,  15.],
       [  7.,  12.,  15.],
       [  7.,  12.,  15.],
       [  7.,  17.,  18.],
       [  7.,  17.,  18.],
       [  8.,  13.,  16.],
       [  8.,  13.,  16.],
       [  8.,  13.,  17.],
       [  8.,  16.,  19.],
       [  8.,  16.,  19.],
       [  8.,  16.,  19.],
       [ 10.,  15.,  18.],
       [ 10.,  18.,  21.],
       [ 15.,  24.,  29.]],

       [[  6.,  11.,  14.],
       [  6.,  11.,  14.],
       [  6.,  11.,  14.],
       [  6.,  11.,  14.],
       [  7.,  12.,  15.],
       [  7.,  12.,  15.],
       [  7.,  12.,  15.],
       [  7.,  12.,  15.],
       [  7.,  15.,  18.],
       [  7.,  15.,  18.],
       [  8.,  13.,  16.],
       [  8.,  13.,  16.],
       [  8.,  13.,  17.],
       [  8.,  16.,  19.],
       [  8.,  16.,  19.],
       [  8.,  16.,  19.],
       [ 10.,  15.,  18.],
       [ 10.,  18.,  21.],
       [ 15.,  24.,  29.]]
]])
```

with the `(1, 3, 19, 3)` shape, I want to retrieve a collection of unique pixels in each row as a new sub-array. So, essentially, I want to do a `np.unique` on each row of 19 pixels. If I do it separately all goes well:

```
np.unique(test_nested_array.squeeze(0)[0], axis=0)

>>> array([[ 6., 11., 14.],
           [ 7., 12., 15.],
           [ 7., 15., 18.],
           [ 8., 13., 16.],
           [ 8., 13., 17.],
           [ 8., 16., 19.],
           [10., 15., 18.],
           [10., 18., 21.],
           [15., 24., 29.]])
```

However, I would like to perform this operation on all rows to improve speed, and I thought I could provide the `axis=2` argument to the `np.unique` call, so the function is calculated over the rows. However, this does not give me the correct output:

```
np.unique(test_nested_array, axis=2)

>>> array([[[[ 6., 11., 14.],
         [ 6., 11., 14.],
         [ 6., 11., 14.],
         [ 7., 12., 15.],
         [ 7., 12., 15.],
         [ 7., 15., 18.],
         [ 8., 13., 16.],
         [ 8., 13., 17.],
         [ 8., 16., 19.],
         [10., 15., 18.],
         [10., 18., 21.],
         [15., 24., 29.]],

        [[11., 11., 14.],
         [13., 11., 14.],
         [15., 11., 14.],
         [ 7., 12., 15.],
         [ 7., 19., 15.],
         [ 7., 17., 18.],
         [ 8., 13., 16.],
         [ 8., 13., 17.],
         [ 8., 16., 19.],
         [10., 15., 18.],
         [10., 18., 21.],
         [15., 24., 29.]],

        [[ 6., 11., 14.],
         [ 6., 11., 14.],
         [ 6., 11., 14.],
         [ 7., 12., 15.],
         [ 7., 12., 15.],
         [ 7., 15., 18.],
         [ 8., 13., 16.],
         [ 8., 13., 17.],
         [ 8., 16., 19.],
         [10., 15., 18.],
         [10., 18., 21.],
         [15., 24., 29.]]]])
```

This output feels strange for me, as the second array kind of seems to be de-duped, but is not sorted as per the documentation, and the first and third arrays are not de-duped at all?

I have also tried to achieve the result by doing an `apply_among_axis` but that errored:

```
np.apply_along_axis(np.unique, 2, test_nested_array)

>>> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (7) into shape (5)
```

I do not really get the `(7)` and `(5)` here, so again no idea. My assumption is that because `np.unique` tries to put the de-duped subarrays into one array and that fails because the de-duped subarray can have different shapes, but I'm not sure what is the best way to approach this in an efficient and fast manner.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Does `[np.unique(test_nested_array.squeeze(0)[i], axis=0) for i in range(3)]` capture your desired o/p? What would be the shape of the final expected o/p?

Comment: Yes, it does capture it. I could do that, but is this the best / most efficient way to do so? Th shape of this is going to be just (3,), as the sub-arrays could be different size of course.

Comment: Given that there could be different number of unique rows per "row of 19 pixels", seems like that the best we could get.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the tip by @Divakar helpt me further, I ended up using `numpy_indexed` package to extract the unique entries like this:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
uniq = npi.unique(data)
```

This turned out much faster for my use-case.